# iPhone SDK view scrolling not rubber banding or using momentum from swipes

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiview

I'm having a fundamental problem with getting scrolling to work **normally** on my iPhone app.  I have two views, each created in IB (although I've tried this programmatically and it makes no difference) which scroll very sloppily.  Instead of the scrolling that we're used to (which is smooth and continues to scroll and eventually dampen and rubber band at the top/bottom), my scrolling only scrolls as long as my finger is in contact with the view.  Swiping down quickly on a view has no more effect than swiping slowly.  And when you scroll beyond the top or bottom, the view just stays there scrolled with empty area above/below.

One of my views is a UITableView and the other is a UIScrollView.  Both have exactly the same problem and are in different XIBs, coupled to different classes, so this is why I think I'm missing a key concept in general.

My UITableView is a child to a UIView (since there is also a nav bar at the top) with my UIViewController's view connected to the UIView.  The referencing outlets datasource and delegate are both hooked to the UITableView.  Nothing is subclassed here aside from the ViewController of course which has overrides to populate the table.

In the second instance, I again have a non-subclassed UIView which my UIViewController's view is connected to.  I have a subclassed UIScrollView as a child to the UIView and then a have a subclassed UIView (with larger size than the scroll view) as a child to the subclassed UIScrollView.  This in itself seems ridiculously complicated to me, but I was not able to get scrolling working at all with fewer than 3 views (again there is a nav bar at the top of the non-subclassed UI-View).  I am overriding drawRect: in my UIScrollView, which is putting the content up fine except for this scrolling issue.

Is there something I'm doing wrong organizationally?  I've come across many suggestions on stackoverflow and other sites for UIScrollView and none make a difference.  And I don't see anyone having scrolling issues with UITableView.  I'm not pasting in any code because I would have to post full classes at this point (making the post ridiculously long) and I believe the problems to really lie with the way I'm using IB.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, it turns out that this has nothing to do with UIKit.  This code is part of a game I'm developing using cocos2d and that framework is what is causing the problem.  For those who are developing on cocos2d, you cannot use FastDirector and expect scrolling to work in UIViews.  Just remove any code like `[[Director sharedDirector] useFastDirector]` and everything will be fine.

Comment: 3 years later...this helped me a lot.  Did you find any other work arounds?  Im using fast director for more accurate touch events.  Can you switch director types?

Comment: I experimented with all the different directors which were added late in the pre 1.0 Cocos release.  I don't remember which really performed better and would have to pull up the code to see what I stuck with, but they definitely all worked aside from FastDirector.  You should experiment, because depending on your app, a different director may perform better for you.

Answer (score 0):

Some code might help narrow down your problem.

In the mean time, try creating a new project in Xcode using the 'Navigation-based Application' template and take a look at how the navigation controller is being created in MainWindow.xib. Take a look at how the UITableViewController subclass called 'RootViewController' is defined and how the corresponding xib is setup too. You'll notice there is no UIScrollView explicitly defined anywhere but you get scrolling functionality from the tableview controller 'for free'.

This should give you a pretty good starting point down the right path. I question the need for overriding drawRect: without seeing some code or fully understanding your goal.

Take a look at:
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html
http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/UsingNavigationControllers/UsingNavigationControllers.html